# Regression Testing Heroku Request Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, heroku, carrierwave, carrierwave-direct

My Rails app currently has a thumbnail upload endpoint which frequently times out on Heroku due to the 30 second request limit. I use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and would like to switch to [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) to solve the problem by doing direct to S3 uploads.

Before I do so, I would like to write a regression test and see it fail with a request timeout. How can I do that?

Most of my tests are high level Selenium/capybara tests, so I tried writing one which stubs the controller action to always throw a timeout error:

```
# Simulates 30 second Heroku timeout for thumbnail uploads.
context 'when PATCH requests timeout' do
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(Api::V1::VideosController).to receive(:update).and_wrap_original do |m, *args|
      if request.content_type == 'multipart/form-data'
        raise Net::HTTPRequestTimeOut
      else
        m.call(*args)
      end
    end
  end

  it 'uploads custom thumbnails direct to S3' do
    signup_and_verify_email(signup_intent: :seller)
    visit_store_via_upload_link
    upload_test_video
    upload_thumbnail
  end
end
```

This fails because `request` is undefined in the context of the block. Before I go further with this, whats the best way to write a test for this scenario?